# Can't get test to run with NUnit on Monodevelop in Linux

Tags: linux, nunit, monodevelop, tcpclient

I'm trying to make some test for a server I made. But can't get to run it.
This is the code:

```
[SetUp]
public override void setUp()
{
    base.setUp ();
    tcpClient = new TcpClient ("132.72.214.127",6666);
}

[Test]
public void TestSuperUserConnection()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Starting SuperUser Test");
    string ans = sendAndReceive (""+0, "admin,1234");
    Assert.IsTrue(ans.Contains("{"));
}

public string sendAndReceive(string type, string args)
{
    try{
        string message = buildJson (type, args);
        Console.WriteLine ("Building Json: {0}", message);
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine ("Sending data");
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        data = new Byte[1024];
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder ();
        int bytes;
        string responseData;
        Console.WriteLine ("Receiving data");
        while((bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) > 0)
        {
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            ans.Append (responseData);
        }
        ServerResponse sr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponse>(ans.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", ans.ToString());
        return ans.ToString ();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Error received: {0}", e);
    }
    return "";
}
```

I try to run it in debug mode and release mode. Also under sudo. And the server always get my request but I can't see anything on my output and the test never ends.
Could there be any problem with console.writeline?
Any thoughts?
I'm using monodevelop 4.2.2, with nunit 2.6.0.0
The output is just: "Running test ServerTest...."
and nothing more

Comment: your question lacks lots of details such as the version of mono you're running, the version of monodevelop, the version of nunit, and the log of what you see in the console until it hangs

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, just added the info